# Complex conditional summary on df in r

Tags: r

I have this df that represented two players (win=1 and win=0) from a pair (id) playing some number of rounds (ttbi) of a game where the winner of each round selects a sound:

```
> dput(for_stack_initial)
structure(list(id = c(20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 
20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 
20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 
20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 
20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 
20230424L), ttbi = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), win = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), sound = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 
4L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))
```

I want to create another column that represents an escalation (esc) in sound between the players. Specifically, I want to calculate the difference in sound between a given player's first sound selection in a win streak and the other player's mean sound selection from the previous win streak. I have done this manually in Excel so that I can provide my exact desired outcome for this sample df. I need the outcome to be exactly:

```
> dput(for_stack_wanted)
structure(list(id = c(20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 
20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 
20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230420L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 
20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 
20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 20230424L, 
20230424L), ttbi = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), win = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), sound = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 
4L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 5L), esc = c(NA, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, -0.5, 
NA, 0.5, 0, NA, -0.5, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 0.5, 1, -1, -3, 3, 2, 
NA, 1.5, NA, 1.5, NA, -1.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))
```

As you can see, there will only be an esc value in rows where the player number (win) is the first in a win streak and the first row of each unique id has to be NA because there is not previous round to compare to.

I have considered doing this manually but my real dataset has over a thousand rows. I imagine there is a tidyverse solution but I am so new to tidyvery that I don't even know where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Grace! 1. Who selects the sound in the first row? 2. I'm guessing it all resets when the id changes?

Comment: Hi @mark! Yes, it does reset with every new pair id. The winner of the first round selects the sound level of the first round. But since there is no previous round, that would selection is "unprovoked" (and therefor cannot be an escalation or de-escalation)

Comment: ah so is the sound of a row the sound of the winner of that round? I thought it was the sound of the previous one!

Comment: Another question: what's with the NAs on rows 4, 5, and 6? Is it only the first number in the winning streak which gets a value, and all others get NA?

Comment: Yes, the sound of each row is for that row's winner. and yes, it only the first number in the winning streak which gets a value (all others get NA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. Create a `streak` column (looks for when the `win` value is different to the `win` value of the previous row, grouped by `id`
2. Find the mean for each streak and id
3. Find the `esc`, subtracting the sound from the previous row's average sound value
4. Change all ones which aren't the first in a streak to be NA
5. Remove the streak and average columns

```
library(dplyr)

for_stack_initial |> 
  mutate(streak = cumsum(win != lag(win, default = first(win))), .by = id) |> 
  mutate(av = mean(sound), .by = c(id, streak)) |>
  mutate(esc = sound - lag(av), .by = id) |>
  mutate(esc = ifelse(row_number() == 1, esc, NA), .by = c(id, streak)) |> 
  select(-streak, -av)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 29 × 5
         id  ttbi   win sound   esc
      <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 20230420     1     1     1  NA  
 2 20230420     2     0     1   0  
 3 20230420     3     1     2   1  
 4 20230420     4     1     1  NA  
 5 20230420     5     1     2  NA  
 6 20230420     6     1     1  NA  
 7 20230420     7     0     1  -0.5
 8 20230420     8     0     2  NA  
 9 20230420     9     1     2   0.5
10 20230420    10     0     2   0  
# ℹ 19 more rows
```